# Vous avez l'air estimer que c'est impossible, ça l'est

Tags: sens, formulation

*Les embrouilles de Calma* de Barry Jonsberg :

Après la mort de Kiffo, Calma, le Pitbull, une policière et quelques membres de l'école de Calma sont réunis dans une salle.

Le Pitbull dit qu'elle est navrée de la mort de Kiffo et qu'elle a mal pour Calma. Celle-ci lui répond qu'elle ne la croit pas.

Le Pitbull dit à Calma :

> Pourtant, et quoi que vous pensiez, j'aime mes pupilles. Trop, même. Il
> serait tellement plus facile d'être populaire. De blaguer, d'amener
> les élèves à m'aimer. Vous avez l'air estimer que c'est impossible,
> **ça l'est**.

Je ne comprends pas le sens du *ça l'est*. Est-ce que la dernière phrase signifie que Calma pense que le Pitbull est incapable d'amener ses élèves à l'aimer et que le Pitbull affirme le contraire ? Ou elle est d'accord avec Calma sur ce point ?

Answer (score 1):

***Ça l'est*** confirme normalement la phrase précédente donc ici, ***c'est impossible***.

Cependant, peut-être que le sens de la phrase est ici l'inverse, et que ***ça l'est*** se rapporte à ***possible***, comme s'il avait été écrit ***vous avez l'air d'estimer que ce n'est pas possible***.

Seul le contexte permet de lever ce doute.

Comment: _Seul le contexte permet de lever ce doute._ Ça reste ambigu malgré le contexte. J'ai relu le texte, mais je n'ai pas compris.

Comment: Si le contexte ne permet pas de lever le doute, je pencherais pour la deuxième option (c'est possible), vu que la phrase commence par *vous avez l'air d'estimer que*, ce qui laisse plus supposer une suite en contradiction qu'en confirmation.

Comment: Oui, c'est ce que j'avais compris, moi aussi, mais je n'étais pas sûre. Pourrais-tu stp d'écrire @ + mon nom dans tes commentaites, parce que sinon je n'ai pas de notification.

Comment: @oreste C'est bizarre, il me semble pourtant qu'on est ici dans un cas où il n'est pas nécessaire de mettre le @. *A post’s author comments on a post you have previously commented on, when the only other (undeleted) comments on the post belong to you or the author.* [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319354/182055)

Comment: *écrire // Il se peut que je sois trop fatiguée ce soir, mais je ne comprends pas ce que dit cette phrase en anglais. Normalement, je comprends les textes en anglais sans problèmes. Quoqu'il en soit, je ne reçois pas de notification lorsque j'écris sous ta réponse et que tu écris un commentaire par la suite. Je ne l'ai jamais reçue dans ces cas-là.

Comment: @oreste La phrase décrit l'un des cas où on reçoit une notification. C'est vrai qu'elle est compliquée à analyser : *(on est notifié) à la suite d'un commentaire fait par l'auteur d'un post que vous avez vous-même commenté et dont les autres commentaires n'appartiennent qu'à vous ou à l'auteur du post.*  Un post étant une question ou une réponse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136090/discussion-between-oreste-and-jlliagre).